# C# - ListView won't refresh from different form

Tags: c#, windows, forms, listview, refresh

```
// PaddlerList (Form 1)
        public void RefreshListView()
        {
            PaddlerListView.Items.Clear();
            PaddlerToList();
            PaddlerListView.Refresh();
            Console.WriteLine("Refresh....");
        }
        public void PaddlerToList() // Just adds 
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < Main.paddlerList.Count(); i++) // Repeats for all
            {
                string[] array = new string[4];
                ListViewItem item;
                array[0] = Main.paddlerList[i].FirstName.ToString();
                array[1] = Main.paddlerList[i].LastName.ToString();
                array[2] = Main.paddlerList[i].Weight.ToString();
                array[3] = Main.paddlerList[i].PreferredSide.ToString();
                item = new ListViewItem(array);
                PaddlerListView.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }

        private void RefreshList_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RefreshListView();
        }


// NewPaddler (Form 2)
            private void SubmitPaddler_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            // Code here
            PaddlerList ListViewRefresh = new PaddlerList(); // Creates an instant of the other form, so it can run the procedure
            ListViewRefresh.RefreshListView();
            }
```

When a new paddler is added (the submit button is pressed), the console outputs "Refresh...." showing that the function has been run, but the ListView doesn't refresh

However, when I set a button on the same form as the ListView, it does refresh the ListView with the new items, when the button is pressed.

I can't work out what the issue is here? I think it's something to do with protection levels of the ListView.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

New Paddler Form

```
    // NewPaddler Form

PaddlerList ListObject_global = null;
public NewPaddler(PaddlerList PaddlerList_Object)
{
  InitializeComponent();
  FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
  ListObject_global = PaddlerList_Object;
}


if (ListObject_global != null)
{
  ListObject_global.RefreshListView(); // Runs function in PaddlerList
}
```

Paddler List Form

```
// PaddlerList Form
public void RefreshListView()
{
  PaddlerToList();
  PaddlerListView.Refresh();
  Console.WriteLine("Refresh....");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a new `PaddlerList` object is created, all member variables, like in your case, `Items`, recieve a fresh start. I think you need to pass the original `PaddlerList` to your second form in order to actualize the correct form.

Comment: I added a .Show() in there too, and it showed a new form with the new paddler. How would I go about passing this between forms as it's not string or something? Thanks